# How to get username from Azure Active Directory using user Id (object id)

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I use Azure AD for authentication in my project and need to get the username of the user by its Id (any user from the company's AD). I found out how to get it using Microsoft graph but it requires a User.Read.All and I don't have such.
Can anyone help with this stuff?
I use .net Core on the back end and Vue.js (MSAL library) on the front end. I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If your application runs as a background service or daemon without a signed-in user you need application permission `User.Read.All` with admin consent. There is no other way how to get username without that permission. Ask your tenant admin to grant `User.Read.All` permission.

If your application access the API as the signed-in user then `User.Read` delegated permission should be enough.

Comment: Hi! Thank you a lot for the response. I tried to get another user's info using a token for with User.Read permissions but get "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." response

Comment: @LevKostychenko Did you add User.Read permission to your app in Azure Portal? But User.Read permission will not work for daemon app.

Comment: Yes, it's added to my app